# Syntax error in .jsx file for ReactJS development

Tags: reactjs, mean-stack

Hi i've started to learn ReactJS and i'm already having difficulty inserting a component into another.

It says there's a syntax error for <   Header /    >

Any idea why?

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {Header} from './Header.jsx';

class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
   var myStyle = {
   fontSize:100,
   color:'black'
   }
      return (
         <div style={myStyle}>
            Hello World!!! this is taking so long
         </div>

         <Header/>
      );
   }
}
export default App;
```

Header.js

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';

class Header extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div className="myHeader">
            header
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of your component must be wrapped in a single tag.

```
return (
     <div>
         <div style={myStyle}>
            Hello World!!! this is taking so long
         </div>

         <Header/>
     </div>
);
```

Comment: What's the error ? Maybe it's not worth opening a new question.

Comment: Sorry you must have seen the question before I deleted it. It was just that I had {} curly brackets around the import name of Header and removing it resolved it. Thank you